# Chrome extension content script not injecting to the DOM when built with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension using React.
I've ejected `create-react-app` and have made necessary changes to emit `content.chunk.js` which is included in `manifest.json` as below

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "Some description",
  "permissions": [],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "My extension",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "css": ["/static/css/content.chunk.css"],
    "js": ["/static/js/content.chunk.js"]
  }]
}
```

my content.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Main from 'extensionContainers/Main';

alert('bazooka!');
const app = document.createElement('div');
app.id = "extension-root";
document.body.appendChild(app);

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, app);
```

after build, when I load my extension this doesn't do anything.
However, when I edit the contents of `content.chunk.js` generated by webpack to `alert("something")`, the extension works fine and shows alert on every URL.

Why is my react code isn't doing anything? There are no error logs.

Comment: The usual reason is that your config produces a module script that only registers its exported functions but never actually invokes them. I don't know react/webpack so I don't know what exactly you need to change in your config, but hopefully there are existing solutions.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't think that's happening. If I add the generated `content.chunk.js` in an HTML page as a script tag, it works as expected. However, through content script I don't see anything happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question if anyone else stumbles upon this.

So, I realized that the Webpack config from `create-react-app@3.0.1` ejection had code split configurations enabled. Which was splitting react library code from my code making it inexecutable.

Here are the settings I changed in the webpack config to get it working. (note that this is only advisable to do when developing chrome extension)

In `webpack.config.js` remove the configuration for `splitChunks` under `optimization` node, and set `runtimeChunk` to `false`.

```
...
optimization: {
  .
  .
  // remove spitChunks config
  splitChunks: {
     chunks: 'all',
     name: false,
  },
  runtimeChunk: true, // set this to false
}
...
```

the generated bundle will now be named as `content.js` (considering `content` as the entry point)
link this `content.js` in your `manifest.json` under `content_scripts` and you're good to go.

Comment: @Vishal which folder should I place content.js?

Comment: @S.J.Lin content.js will be bundled in your build folder at /static/js/content.js just reference it in your manifest.json and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Now, we don't need to edit the `Webpack.config.js` anymore instead, we can configure our own using

1. `customize-cra`,
2. `react-app-rewired`,
3. `copy-webpack-plugin`,
4. `react-app-rewire-multiple-entry`

1 and 2 will overwrite the `webpack` default configuration, 3 to copy all of our assets files, and 4 to add multiple files

Just install it:

```
npm -i customize-cra react-app-rewired copy-webpack-plugin react-app-rewire-multiple-entry --save-dev
```

Yarn

```
yarn add customize-cra react-app-rewired copy-webpack-plugin react-app-rewire-multiple-entry --dev
```

## Configuration

create a `config-overrides.js` file in your root directory `/` and put use this code

```
const {
   override,
   overrideDevServer,
   addWebpackPlugin
} = require("customize-cra");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const multipleEntry = require('react-app-rewire-multiple-entry')([
   {
      // points to the popup entry point
      entry: 'src/popup/index.js',
      template: 'public/popup.html',
      outPath: '/popup.html'
   },
   {
      // points to the options page entry point
      entry: 'src/options/index.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      outPath: '/index.html'
   }
]);

const devServerConfig = () => config => {
   return {
      ...config,
      // webpackDevService doesn't write the files to desk
      // so we need to tell it to do so so we can load the
      // extension with chrome
      writeToDisk: true
   }
}

const copyPlugin = new CopyPlugin({
   patterns: [
      // copy assets
      { from: 'public', to: '' },
      { from: 'src/background.js', to: '' }
   ]
})

module.exports = {
   webpack: override(
      addWebpackPlugin(
         copyPlugin
      ),
      multipleEntry.addMultiEntry,
   ),
   devServer: overrideDevServer(
      devServerConfig()
   ),

};
```

go ahead and create two folders in `src/`, `options/`, and `popup` containing the `index.js` and `app.js` files, mean copy all the files from `src/` when you install `React` and past it to these both folders. for the `background.js` file you should put this on the `src/`:

```
/
   src/
      background.js
      index.js // empty file only
      options
         index.js
         app.js
         app.css
      popup
         index.js
         app.js
         app.css
```

Also overide the `script` in the package.json file to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

now you don't need to reload the extension after changes, it will automatically trigger when you save your code.

another file is to create is `.env` in the root directory and past this:

```
INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false
```

Now run the command `yarn start` or `npm start`, load the extension you should be good to go!

[Resource to learn](https://dev.to/jamalx31/use-create-react-app-to-develop-a-chrome-extension-14ld)